# Things to do on a production server

Tags: django, production-environment

We just launched our product recently. It's been great, I couldn't have done it without StackOverflow. You guys have been great. Thank You.

So yeah, getting to the question -
**What are the fundamental things that I should take care of in a production environment?**
The kind of answers I'm looking for would be for example - run a cron job to take regular backup of your database etc..

Answer (score 0):

Well besides a cronjob for backing up the database (make sure you save the old backup to avoid corruption) theres the user upload directory..
I suppose you can create an image of the upload path and files at any given interval that suits your site's activity.

Also I'd always make sure logfiles are maxed in size limit so you don't end up with 10 miles of text logs crammed in one file..

Security stuff tends to be overwhelming, however basically make sure the directories are chmod/chown properly. Probably want to avoid unwanted ssh access, so either use the iptables to make sure it's hard to get in, or atleast update your password from time to time..

I think this topic could go on for ages :-)

Answer (score 0):

if your are using apache server then

[this article](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Server-Limits-for-Apache-Security/) ( http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Server-Limits-for-Apache-Security/ )  will be very usefull to you.

plus

Compress your graphics and use Django compressor application to reduce significant js/css 
load ..

http://coderpriyu.blogspot.com/2011/12/django-compressing-cssjs-files-with.html